# Injecting one view scoped bean in another view scoped bean causes it to be recreated

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, dependency-injection, managed-bean

I need to use some data saved in a view scoped bean in an other view scoped bean.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Attivita implements Serializable {
    //
}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Nota implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty("#{attivita}")
    private Attivita attivita;

    // Getter and setter.
}
```

Now, maybe my theory about it is still quite poor, I have noticed that when `#{attivita}` is injected, the `Attivita` constructor is invoked and thus creating another instance. Is it the right behaviour? What about if I want to reference the same instance and not create a new one?

Comment: Take care about marking the correct responses. Stack overflow is not only about questions it's about answers too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will happen if you're navigating from one to the other view on a postback. A view scoped bean is not tied to a request, but to a view. So when you navigate to a new view, it will get a brand new instance of the view scoped bean. It won't reuse the same bean instance which is associated with a previous view.

I understand that the `attivita` bean is created on the initial view and reused on postback. I understand that `nota` bean is associated with the new view where you're navigating to. When injecting `attivita` in it, it will simply get a new and distinct instance even though there's another instance in the very same request. This is all expected (and admittedly a bit unintuitive) behaviour.

There is no standard JSF solution for this. CDI solves this with `@ConversationScoped` (the bean lives as long as you explicitly tell it to live) and the CDI extension MyFaces CODI goes a bit further with `@ViewAccessScoped` (the bean lives as long as the navigated view references it).

You could however workaround this by storing the bean as an attribute in the request scope.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Attivita implements Serializable {

    public String submit() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getRequestMap().put("attivita", this);
        return "nota";
    }

}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Nota implements Serializable {

    private Attivita attivita;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        attivita = (Attivita) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getRequestMap().get("attivita");
    }

}
```

Note that this is rather hacky. There may be better solutions depending on the concrete functional requirement. Also note that you should in the `nota` view reference the desired `Attivita` bean instance as `#{nota.attivita}` and *not* as `#{attivita}`, because it would give you a new and different instance, for the reasons already explained before.

Comment: This works for sure - I had the same issue. However, it is very hacky as you stated, and is yet ANOTHER huge shortcoming of JSF. It kind of eliminates the purpose of CDI or Managed Properties when you have to add a PostConstruct and have to manually pull a bean out of the Faces Context. Is there a plan to have @ViewAccessScoped added to the standard JSF API and not as part of Myfaces only?

Comment: @GreenieMeanie: JSF 2.2 added `@FlowScoped` to cover this, but unfortunately it still requires a bit of XML configuration and autogenerated request parameters, because it also needed to survive GET requests. It's, say, between `@ViewAccessScoped` and `@SessionScoped`. As a probable "better solution", you can think of just redirecting it with entity ID as param, or conditionally rendering part of the very same view with another include. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o

Comment: Are you suggesting to have view a.xhtml have a "dummy" include to b.xhtml and perhaps wrap all the content of b.xhtml in one huge ui:fragment that only actually renders anything when it is redirected to (via b.xhtml) and NOT when it is included as a dummy reference from a.xhtml?

Comment: @GreenieMeanie: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108668/how-to-ajax-refresh-the-main-content-part-by-navigation-menu (apply the idea on this single "Wizard" page, not on entire site).

Answer (score 1):

Your `attivita` bean is `@ViewScoped` and that doesn't guarantee that your instance will be hold in session. You need a `@SessionScoped` bean. However, if you need `attivita` for some reason to be `@ViewScoped`, then you can pass params through them in other ways, e.g. using `viewParam` or using other `@SessionScoped` bean between them.

**Page Params**

http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-page-params-and-page-actions/

**JSF 2 Managed Bean Scopes**

http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes