# JSF 2.0 communication between two @ViewScoped, Inject

Tags: jsf, communication, managed-bean, view-scope

I have huge problem with communication between two @ViewScoped Managed Beans.
Following listing show the way i have been done this.
UserAddEditMB is injected to UserSearchMB and after user click button with onAdd action  it calls UserAddEditMB init method. 
in the end there is navigation rule to my second form, but u1 nad u2 are null.

Is this is good way to perform communication in two @ViewScoped Managed beans ?

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserSearchMB {

@ManagedProperty(value ="#{userAddEditMB}")
private UserAddEditMB userAddEditMB;

public void onAdd(){
    userAddEditMB.init(String param1, String param2);
    return "userAddEdit";
}
...
}


@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserAddEditMB {

private String u1;
private String u2;

public void init(String param1, String param2){
    this.u1 = param1;
    this.u2 = param2;
}
....
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Injecting one view scoped bean in another view scoped bean causes it to be recreated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231044/injecting-one-view-scoped-bean-in-another-view-scoped-bean-causes-it-to-be-recre)

Answer (score -1):

I post as answer because comment is too small.
You can try to get UserSearchMB from UserAddEditMB:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
UserSearchMB test= (UserSearchMB) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{userSearchMB}", UserSearchMB .class);
```

Comment: Please experiment yourself first before posting off as an answer.