# Dynamic <ui:include src> depending on <ui:repeat var> doesn't include anything

Tags: jsf, dynamic, jsf-2, uirepeat, uiinclude

I am new to JSF and I am struggling with dynamicaly rendering included pages. My code looks like this:

MenuBean

```
@ViewScoped
public class MenuBean implements Serializable {

    private MenuItem[] menuItems = new MenuItem[] {
        new MenuItem("page_1", "/page_1.xhtml"),
        new MenuItem("page_2", "/page_2.xhtml"),
    };

    private String selectedItemLabel;

    //...
}
```

MenuItem

```
public class MenuItem implements Serializable {

    private String label;
    private String page;

    //...
}
```

index.xhtml

```
    <ui:repeat var="menuItem" value="#{menuBean.menuItems}">                                    
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{menuBean.selectedItemLabel eq menuItem.label}" layout="block">
            <h:outputText value="#{menuBean.selectedItemLabel}" />                              
            <ui:include src="#{menuItem.page}" />                                           
        </h:panelGroup>                                                                     
    </ui:repeat>
```

The result is 2 buttons rendered. Whenever I click any button the label inside conditionaly rendered panelGroup appears but included page doesn't. If I change 'menuItem1' var from first ui:repeat it works but it is really unpredictable. For example if I hardcode setSelectedItemLabel parameter to 'page_1' then when I click to button_1 page_1 is displayed but even if I click to button_2 page_2 (!?) is displayed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're facing a view build time vs view render time problem. This is essentially the same problem which is already answered in detail in [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) In that answer, replace "JSTL" with "ui:include". To the point, the `<ui:repeat>` runs during view render time, while the `<ui:include>` has already run during view build time before.

You'll understand that the only solution is to replace the `<ui:repeat>` by another tag which runs during view build time, such as JSTL `<c:forEach>`.

Note that I don't guarantee that it will solve the concrete functional requirement which you've in mind. Using JSTL may have undesirable "side effects" (which are however explainable, understandable and workaroundable).

#### See also:

- [How to ajax-refresh dynamic include content by navigation menu? (JSF SPA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108668/how-to-ajax-refresh-dynamic-include-content-by-navigation-menu-jsf-spa)