# Is it ok to use a ui:repeat inside a ui:include

Tags: jsf, facelets, uirepeat, uiinclude

We all know the difference between build time and render time. It is definitely not a great idea to put a `<ui:include>` tag (build time) inside a `<ui:repeat>` (render time), but is the opposite okay to do? Can we use `<ui:repeat>` inside a `<ui:include>`?

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are OK.

> *It is definitely not a great idea to put a `<ui:include>` tag (build time) inside a `<ui:repeat>` (render time)*

This is not true. You can safely do so. The only limitation is that you can't use the `var` of `<ui:repeat>` inside `src` of `<ui:include>`. In other words, the following approach will **not** work:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/#{item.foo}.xhtml" />
</ui:repeat>
```

This will only work when you replace `<ui:repeat>` by `<c:forEach>`.

But if you are not doing that, e.g.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/foo.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="foo" value="#{item.foo}" />
    </ui:include>
</ui:repeat>
```

Then there is no problem. Everything will work just fine.

---

> *but is the opposite okay to do? Can we use `<ui:repeat>` inside a `<ui:include>`?*

You can also safely do so. If you face a problem, just press "Ask Question" button on right top.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)
- [Dynamic <ui:include src> depending on <ui:repeat var> doesn't include anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916484/dynamic-uiinclude-src-depending-on-uirepeat-var-doesnt-include-anything/)