# Partial Page Rendering (primefaces) need two times click before changing

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108668/how-to-ajax-refresh-the-main-content-part-by-navigation-menu/7113961#7113961) answer to rendering a part of my primefaces page but the problem is that I need to click twice before getting the part changed is there a solution ?

this is my code

index.xhtml

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
 <h:head>
 </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:panelGroup id="header" layout="block">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="menu" layout="block">
        <h:form>
            <f:ajax render=":content">
                <p:commandButton value="next" action="#{navBean.next}" />            
                <p:commandButton value="back" action="#{navBean.back}" />
            </f:ajax>
        </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="content" layout="block">
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{navBean.activePage == 'firstAjax'}">
            <ui:include src="firstAjax.xhtml" />
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{navBean.activePage == 'lastAjax'}">
            <ui:include src="lastAjax.xhtml" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
   </h:body>
  </html>
```

and this is my managedBean

```
 package com.project.beans;

 import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
 import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

 @ManagedBean(name = "navBean")
 @SessionScoped
 public class NavBean {

private String activePage = "firstAjax";

public String getActivePage() {
    return activePage;
}

public void setActivePage(String activePage) {
    this.activePage = activePage;
}

public void next() {
    System.out.println("next in " + activePage);
    this.setActivePage("lastAjax");
    System.out.println("next out " + activePage);
}

public void back() {
    System.out.println("back in " + activePage);
    this.setActivePage("firstAjax");
    System.out.println("back out " + activePage);
}
}
```

the firstAjax.xhtml and the lastAjax.xhtml is nearly the same

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:form>
    <h2>content first</h2>
</h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is not working because PrimeFaces has its own ajax engine. You have to use it when using `p:commandButton`. You don't need to use `p:ajax` tag, because `p:commandButton` has ajax behaviour activated by default, just use the `update` attribute (equivalent to the `render` attribute of `f:ajax` component):

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="next" action="#{navBean.next}" update=":content"/>            
    <p:commandButton value="back" action="#{navBean.back}" update=":content"/>
</h:form>
```

If you want to stick to plain jsf use this instead (it looks much more like the example by BalusC you mentioned):

```
<h:form>
    <f:ajax render=":content" >
        <h:commandButton value="next" action="#{navBean.next}" />            
        <h:commandButton value="back" action="#{navBean.back}" />
    </f:ajax>
</h:form>
```

As a final note, it must be said that `p:ajax` tag (at least in PrimeFaces 4.0) doesn't support the syntax we are using here, outside the `p:commandButton` components, because it's not able to determine the event attribute and therefore it throws: `<p:ajax> Event attribute could not be determined: null`