# action-method in backing bean not invoked when clicking on a commandButton in an AJAX-loaded page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, action, commandbutton

My JSF template has a section that includes another page:

```
<p:outputPanel id="foo">
    <ui:include src="#{bean.page}" />
</p:outputPanel>
```

`bean.page` is set in the bean's `@PostConstruct` method to default page **a.xhtml** ==> page a is loaded and everything behaves as expected.

Now, I set `bean.page` to **b.xhtml** and update the `<p:outputPanel id="foo">` ==> page b is loaded but whenever I click on an `<h:commandButton>`, its action-method is never called.

[How to ajax-refresh dynamic include content by navigation menu? (JSF SPA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108668/how-to-ajax-refresh-the-main-content-part-by-navigation-menu) has an answer that says that any postback in an `<ui:include>` page will fail, when the included page contains a `<h:form>`; the reason is a missing view state. But when I click on the `<h:commandButton>` and analyze the posted data with Firebug, I see that param **javax.faces.ViewState**  with the right value was sent to the server. But anyway, the button's action-method is never invoked.

Comment: Could you upload the bean class code where you have your page member?

Comment: The `<h:commandButton>` should be wrapped in an `<h:form>` anyway.