# How to show jsf page below tabMenu after clicking on menuitem

Tags: jsf, layout, primefaces

I need your assistant in showing the target jsf page contents below the tabMenu after clicking on the menuitem. The tabMenu code is:

```
<p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{param.i}">
<p:menuitem value="Requests" url="/jsf/Requests.jsf" icon="ui-icon-search">
<f:param name="i" value="1" />
</p:menuitem>
<p:menuitem value="Pendings" url="/jsf/Pending.jsf" icon="ui-icon-search">
<f:param name="i" value="1" />
</p:menuitem>
</p:tabMenu>
```

Suppose the user clicks on the "Requests" menuitem, I would like the Requests.jsf to be shown below the tabMenu, so how can I achieve this?

Currently it is opening in a new page.

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108668/how-to-ajax-refresh-the-main-content-part-by-navigation-menu/

Comment: @BalusC it is similar to what I am looking for, however I didn't understand the solution and how it works.

Comment: Then investigate and get back with new detailed questions when things do not work

Comment: This link has helped alot
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108668/how-to-ajax-refresh-the-main-content-part-by-navigation-menu/