# Ajax rendered jsf page doesn't bind bean values

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a xhtml page which has a page included through a value of a bean which is updated through ajax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:body>
    <div class="ui-fluid">
        <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="false" closable="true" />
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:panel id="panelInfo" header="Dados Local Instalação">
                <h:outputLabel for="tipoFornecimento" value="Tipo de Fornecimento"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoFornecimento" value="#{cadastroController.localInstalacao.tipoFornecimento}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroController.tiposFornecimento}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputLabel for="familiaEquipamento" value="Família"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="familiaEquipamento" value="#{cadastroController.familia}" required="true">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroController.familias}"/>
                    <f:ajax listener="#{cadastroController.setarEquipamentoPelaFamilia}" render=":form:panelEquipamento"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:panel>
            <p:panel id="panelEndereco" header="Endereço">
                <ui:include src="/logradouro.xhtml"/>
            </p:panel>
            <p:panel id="equipamentoNa" header="Equipamento NA">
                <ui:include src="/equipamentoNa.xhtml"/>
            </p:panel>
            <p:panel id="panelEquipamento" header="Equipamento">
                <ui:include src="#{cadastroController.panelEquipamento}"/>
            </p:panel>
            <p:commandButton value="Salvar" actionListener="#{cadastroController.salvarLocalInstalacao}" ajax="false"/>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

When I change the value of the selectOneMenu familiaEquipamento it triggers a method in the bean which instatiate a bean and adds the correspondent xhtml to the page

```
public void setarEquipamentoPelaFamilia() {
    switch(familia) {
        case AL:
            localInstalacao.setEquipamento(new Alimentador());
            setPanelEquipamento("alimentador.xhtml");
            break;
        case BF:
        case CD:
        case CDA:
        case CDP:
        case CO:
        case CR:
        case CT:
            localInstalacao.setEquipamento(new ChaveFaca());
            setPanelEquipamento("chaveFaca.xhtml");
            break;
        case FF:
        case FP:
        case FR:
        case FT: 
        case FU:
            localInstalacao.setEquipamento(new ChaveFusivel());
            setPanelEquipamento("chaveFusivel.xhtml");
            break;
        case RG:
            localInstalacao.setEquipamento(new BancoRegulador());
            setPanelEquipamento("reguladorTensao.xhtml");
            break;
        case RL:
            localInstalacao.setEquipamento(new Religador());
            setPanelEquipamento("religador.xhtml");
            break;
        case BC:
            localInstalacao.setEquipamento(new BancoCapacitor());
            setPanelEquipamento("bancoCapacitor.xhtml");
            break;
        case TD:
        case TDP:
            localInstalacao.setEquipamento(new Trafo());
            setPanelEquipamento("transformador.xhtml");
            break;
        case SL:
            localInstalacao.setEquipamento(new Seccionalizador());
            setPanelEquipamento("seccionalizador.xhtml");
            break;
    }
    localInstalacao.getEquipamento().setFamilia(familia);
}
```

I.E. I choose the familia 'AL', so it sets the equipamento to new Alimentador() and returns the page 'alimentador.xhtml'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
        <p:outputLabel for="fasesEquipamento" value="Qtd Fases: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="fasesEquipamento" value="#{cadastroController.localInstalacao.equipamento.fases}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroController.fases}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:outputLabel for="nrAlimentador" value="Número Alimentador: " />
        <p:inputMask mask="9?9" id="nrAlimentador" value="#{cadastroController.localInstalacao.equipamento.nrAlimentador}"/>
        <p:outputLabel for="nrEquipamento" value="Número Equipamento: " />
        <p:inputMask mask="9?9999" id="nrEquipamento" value="#{cadastroController.localInstalacao.equipamento.nrEquipamento}"/>
        <p:outputLabel for="nrEquipamentoAnterior" value="Número Equipamento Anterior: " />
        <p:inputMask mask="9?9999" id="nrEquipamentoAnterior" value="#{cadastroController.localInstalacao.equipamento.nrEquipamentoAnterior}"/>
        <p:outputLabel for="nrSubestacao" value="Número Subestação: " />
        <p:inputMask mask="9?99" id="nrSubestacao" value="#{cadastroController.localInstalacao.equipamento.nrSubestacao}"/>
        <p:outputLabel for="potencia" value="Potencia: " />
        <p:inputMask mask="9?99.9" id="potencia" value="#{cadastroController.localInstalacao.equipamento.potencia}"/>
        <p:outputLabel for="regionalEquipamento" value="Regional: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="regionalEquipamento" value="#{cadastroController.localInstalacao.equipamento.regional}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroController.regionais}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
</ui:composition>
```

I'm using a ViewScoped ManagedBean, but after submitting the form, the values which were added through ajax in the 'alimentador.xhtml' are not binded to the bean localInstalacao

Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind. I managed to fix it by upgrading to mojarra 2.2. It seems like a bug described on [link]https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108668/how-to-ajax-refresh-dynamic-include-content-by-navigation-menu

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I managed to fix it by upgrading to Mojarra 2.2
It seems like a known bug described on [JAVASERVERFACES - 1492](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492)

To upgrade the version of Mojarra in JBOSS AS 7.1 follow these steps [Upgrading Mojarra](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/6-2/installing-liferay-on-jboss-7-1#upgrading-mojarra)