# Dynamic page loading @ViewScoped beans are not destroyed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, single-page-application, jsf-2.2, view-scope

I am using JSF with Primefaces to load pages dynamically. all my beans are in @ViewScoped. When I navigate the beans are not destroyed.

Here is my code samples

My template

```
<ui:include src="topbar.xhtml" />

    <ui:include src="leftmenu.xhtml" />

    <div id="layout-portlets-cover" class="fontRegular">
        <ui:insert name="content">
           Template
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

<h:form id="menuform">
        <ps:menu id="sm_leftmenu">
            <p:submenu id="sm_master" label="#{bundle.Master}" icon="icon-database" >
                <p:menuitem value="#{bundle.Company}" action="#{homePageBean.handleCommandLink()}" update=":content" icon="">
                    <f:param name="centerSrc" value="/master/Company.xhtml" />
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="#{bundle.Customer}" action="#{homePageBean.handleCommandLink()}" update=":content" icon="">
                    <f:param name="centerSrc" value="/master/Customer.xhtml" />
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="#{bundle.Supplier}" action="#{homePageBean.handleCommandLink()}" update=":content" icon="">
                    <f:param name="centerSrc" value="/master/Supplier.xhtml" />
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="#{bundle.Employee}" action="#{homePageBean.handleCommandLink()}" update=":content" icon="">
                    <f:param name="centerSrc" value="/master/Employee.xhtml" />
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="#{bundle.CategoryWork}" action="#{homePageBean.handleCommandLink()}" update=":content" icon="">
                    <f:param name="centerSrc" value="/master/CategoryWork.xhtml" />
                </p:menuitem>
            </p:submenu>
        </ps:menu>
    </h:form>
```

The homepagebean just returns the URL set through f:param

Only the homepagebean is @SessionScoped otherwise all the other beans in the application are @ViewScoped

I also tried using a navigation rule in faces-config as below but the result is the same.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>HomePageBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>Utility.HomePageBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/Home.xhtml</from-view-id> 
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{homePageBean.handleCommandLink}</from-action>
        <to-view-id>>/Home.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect></redirect>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: Your `<from-action>` doesn't match, so that navigation case is never invoked. Nonetheless, this all is fishy. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7108668

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I am doing something wrong here, I will try to do as in the above example.